# Is there an alternative wrapping for tamales?

Tags: mexican-cuisine, tamales

I'd like to have a go at making tamales, but the corn husk wrappers are hard to come by here. Is there anything I can use as a substitute wrapper?

Comment: I guess it's also hard to get fresh corn? It's just about the right time of year for that, depending where you are.

Comment: Not hard, but most fresh corn is usually trimmed and portioned so I can't get the husks from them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've had the same problem once. The first substitute is [banana leaves](http://simplyrecipes.com/recipes/vegetarian_banana_leaf_tamales/). But they're not easy to find either.

The second one is using [big leaves of chard](http://www.guiadetacos.com/d/fotos/tamales_atoles/tamales_de_acelgas_michoacanos.jpg). Tamales will be done in the same time and you could eat the leaf if you want. I've tried it once and it came out great.

Here it's a recipe for [tamales from Michoacan made with chard](http://www.guiadetacos.com/recetas_mexicanas/tamales_atoles/41/tamales-de-acelgas-michoacanos-receta.html). Here it is a graphic [step by step recipe for tamales with chard](http://diariodeunamamaocupada.blogspot.mx/2011/05/tamales-sin-culpa-paso-paso.html). They are written in Spanish, let me know if you need a translator ;)

PS. My mexican mother in law used to do it with chard.

Comment: Banana leaves do work well and taste good.  They are often obtainable, frozen, at Asian markets as well as Latin ones.

Comment: Yes, I can get hold of banana leaves.

Answer (score 4):

My mom (from Guadalajara) used to often wrap them in parchment paper, since it can withstand being heated/steamed. I don't know why she started doing it - probably because it annoyed her that the delicious filling often oozed out of the tamales during the steaming. Anyway, Just to make sure, I would use double sheets the first time you try the parchment to replace the corn husks. There really wont be any difference in flavor.

Answer (score 3):

You could use banana leaves or avocado leaves, though I'm not sure those would be easier to come by. If you can't get a hold of any of those I would try wrapping them in parchment.

Comment: You can also get grape leaves in a jar.  Bonus: They're edible.